# GPS returning true Y values but random X values in specific phone

Tags: android, gps, location, sony

One of the phones we test on recently started to provide us with wrong location data. It's weird in the way that it only gives random X coordinates, but correct Y coordinates. I tried to reproduce the problem but I couldn't be successful. I currently think that problem occurs randomly but thought someone might have experienced a similar issue and help us about it.

The phone is Sony E6603 using Android 7.1.1. There are around 5-10 phones we test on but haven't come across something like this.

[image: img]